# Erasing distant which-way information

Tags: quantum-eraser

In a [quantum eraser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_eraser_experiment) experiment, you have which-way information, which can destroy interference, but then choose to erase it, and get the interference back.  This which-way information is often carried together with the potentially interfering object.  For example, you can send photons through a double slit experiment, with polarizing filters in the slits, and now your photons are both the things that potentially interfere, and the things that carry the tag of polarization.

However, it's also possible to separate the which-way information in space from the interfering particle.  For example, in the electron double slit experiment, you can shine light in the holes, and any reflected light travels away from the electron.  Or consider this screen grab from a [video about the quantum eraser](http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2021/10/the-delayed-choice-quantum-eraser.html):

[image: Quantum eraser setup]

where, after a double slit, there's a crystal which converts a single photon into two entangled ones (of lower energy).

This allows us to destroy the which-way information later, e.g. by absorbing the photons, or putting them through some apparatus where they become coincident and can't be distinguished.  What happens to the pattern on the screen in this case?  What if we delay the destruction of which-way information until long after the potentially interfering particles have hit the screen?

Comment: The QE or DCQE experiments retrocausality is generally considered a misconception, see wikipedia. Unfortunately Sabine's video perpetuates the myth.

Answer (score -1):

One of the "mysteries" of the photon is it ability to choose certain more probable paths .... historically we say the photon interferes withs itself.  But Feynman put forward the path integral approach where mathematically we sum/square all the phases for all the paths between 2 points A and B. We then repeat for AC, AD, AE etc etc eventually the DSE pattern will emerge on the screen (B,C,D,E,etc).

An additional consideration is that an excited electron (ready to emit a photon) is already strongly interacting with the EM field (virtually) ... Photons in DCQE can choose to take paths where they are interacting with both slits (i.e. pattern) or choosing to go directly to detectors where the path is known .... the setup of the experiment has enabled these options.

The delay in the arms/paths can be any length, but the "delayed choice" has generally been debunked ..... The photons have determined their paths at the time of emission .... their paths can change if objects (lenses, filters, etc) are rapidly placed in the intended paths .... but these changes would destroy the original entanglement.